# Continued Issues with NPM Install

Tags: sharepoint, node-modules, sharepoint-online, spfx

I've been at this for over an hour and all I have managed to conclude is that I need help.

I'm on a new computer where I haven't been doing SharePoint Framework development, but now a bug has come up with one of the web parts and I need to get back at it.  I tried to do an npm install of my cloned code when I started getting a series of failures/errors.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - Stowers Institute for Medical Research\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\ls2527\\OneDrive - SIMR\\Desktop\\helixpublicationsv2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python311\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python311\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ls2527\\OneDrive - SIMR\\Desktop\\helixpublicationsv2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ls2527\OneDrive - SIMR\Desktop\helixpublicationsv2\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ls2527\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T22_36_29_981Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm not a full-time dev and I have gone months without doing any SPFx coding, clearly, so please be gentle.  Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide in getting my dev environment back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You are using NodeJs v18.14.2, which is not compatible with SPFx (yet!) Use the compatibility matrix, located at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility to determine the version of NodeJs you need to install.

I HIGHLY recommend using Node Version Manager (nvm) that will allow you to switch easily between versions of NodeJs. There are nvm versions available for MacOS/Linux at https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm and Windows at https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows. The extra 20 minutes to set up nvm will save you hours of uninstalling/installing different versions of NodeJs as you work with SPFx projects with different versions.

Shameless plug: I have a guide on setting up SPFx on a new computer on my blog at https://www.donkirkham.com/blog/spfx2022/. I cover nvm and how to use it.

The other thing is that since you attempted to do an npm install with the incorrect version, I have also seen issues once you try again on the correct version, having to do with SASS.  If you are still having isssues, try running the following command.  `npm rebuild node-sass`

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!  I thought I had set it up and then all of that info went out of my brain apparently when this new bug ticket came into my queue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have installed unsupported version the maximum supported version was node JS version 16x or below

[image]

Follow the below link to setup & configure you SharePoint Development setup for Online/2016/2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Also you can use NVM (Node Version Manager) to setup & manage multiple node JS version on your development machine. use the below link to setup NVM.

Download Setup Here:- https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Installation Steps - https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows